# Modeling the influence of events order on probability

Tags: data-mining, probability, sequence

The case is to model if the sequence of events influences the probability of binary target variable. We have for example five different events which occur in time (event: A,B,C,D,E). They can occur in order from 1 to 5. I would like to check if the order of their occurrence influences the target variable.

My first idea was to convert the time of occurrence into numbers from 1 to 5 and then for example use logistic regression.

Do You know any other practices? 
Any whitepapers and ideas will be helpful.

Comment: From the looks of it you're simply [hypothesis testing the equality of two binomial distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/test-if-two-binomial-distributions-are-statistically-different-from-each-other). The other details seem irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If the order in which the events appears matters, consider using a recurrent neural network. The setup that you propose is invariant to event ordering, whereas in a RNN the events are fed in in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large enough sample size, you can indeed carry this out the way you propose.

For five events, you have 120 ($^5P_5$) possible permutations of the order of events. This allows you to run a logistic regression with 120 dummy independent variables, each of which corresponds to a permutation of your order of events. The F-test of this regression will function as a significance test to see if there is any difference in frequency of your outcome between different orderings of events.

This does require a large sample size, however. A good rule of thumb is at least 20 observations per independent variable in a General Linear Model, so if you have a few thousand samples, we'd expect this model to fit reasonably well.

This does assume you have a relatively small number of events. Five seems manageable, but as your number of events increases, you quickly run into problems as your number of independent variables grows factorially.